# selenium chromedriver launch but takes long time for page load

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara, selenium-chromedriver, homebrew

I am using the chromedriver version 2.36 from brew package manager. It was working fine. But suddenly I'm facing problem loading pages. The driver launches the browser, but page loading takes forever and timeout happens eventually.
 I tried setting proxy to null for the driver but in vain.
 Also tried `brew uninstall chromedriver` and reinstalling again.

The browser launches with the below message and shows timeout

```
Randomized with seed 58972..

Net::ReadTimeout
```

Comment: Is it getting timeout after 60 seconds?

Comment: I've set timeout to 180 seconds. So timeout happens after 180 seconds

Comment: Then what's the problem? Increase the timeout! By the way how did you set the timeout? `@driver.manage.timeouts.page_load = 180` ?

Comment: Yes setting timeout in the same way. The timeout ideally shouldn't be happening. It was loading quicker before a day. Now since the page loading is delayed, it shows timeout. But the actual site is loading fine.

Comment: If page loading is delayed, then it has to wait, it would not timeout. Can you please check the timeout once again? I suspect it's getting timeout at 60 even thought you set it to be 180

Comment: chromedriver v37 is most recent: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.37/  And FWIW--if you are jacking up timeouts to 180 seconds--that's not good...

Comment: @Rajagopalan timeout is happening only after 180 seconds.

Comment: The issue got resolved all of a sudden. It existed for a day. And disappeared the next day when tried running spec. The behaviour occurs on and off.

Comment: @Sam I wonder how it happens, because in ruby binding it's not setting the timeout in the required variable, For me it happens after 60 seconds, so I go to prototype file and hard the seconds which I required.

Comment: @Rajagopalan Currently I'm hardcoding the seconds for timeout 
`client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new,
  client.read_timeout = 180`

Comment: @Sam So this code makes you to for 180 seconds `after a click` ?

Comment: @Rajagopalan yes.

Comment: Okay, so you are not using page_load timeout?

Comment: @Rajagopalan No